# Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a Google map in my android application, but the logs are giving me this error : `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)`

Although i'm following the tutorials provided by [code.tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com),where my xml file(activity_finddrone.xml) is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
     >

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                class="com.example.mhk.myapplication.FindDroneActivity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Although I found a previous similar questions, but the answers didn't do me any help.
Thank you :)

Comment: In the layout, the `<fragment>`'s `class` attribute must point to a `Fragment` class, not the hosting `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong in this code

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.example.mhk.myapplication.FindDroneActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

In class you have to provide class of fragment not activity. Or you want to use google map then you have to do like

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

You can check official [document](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) for that.